# Expanded div pushes other divs out of way even when using z-index

Tags: html, css

Trying to have 20 messages, with details, shown on a page. The details info is fixed. The message can vary from nothing to about 240 characters. Want to display first part of message and then, when hovering, have the rest shown.

I can do it fine but when the message box expands it pushes other boxes out of the way. I have researched this lots and looked answers here but...

```
  <style>
        #bigboy {
            width:100%;
        }
        #boxout {
            width:200px;
            background-color: red;
            height:150px;
            margin:10px;
            float:left;
        }
        #boxout:hover {
            height:inherit;
            min-height:150px;
        }
        #boxin {
            width:180px;
            background-color: white;
            margin:10px;
            right:10px;
            font-size:1em;
            border:1px;
            overflow:hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            height: 130px;
            line-height: 1.8em;
        }
        #boxin:hover {
            word-wrap: initial;
            overflow: visible;
            height: inherit;
            min-height:130px;
            line-height: 1.8em;
            clear:both;
        }
    </style>
     <div id="bigboy">
        <div id="boxout">
            <div id="boxin">1</div>
        </div>
        <div id="boxout">
            <div id="boxin">22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 2222 22222 22 22 22 22 22 22 2222 22222 22
                22 22 22 22 2222 22222 22 22 222 22 22 22 22 22 22 2222 22222 22 22 22
                22 22 2222 22222 22 22 22 22 22 2222 222"</div>
        </div>
        <div id="boxout">
            <div id="boxin">3</div>
        </div>
        <div id="boxout">
            <div id="boxin">3</div>
        </div>
        <div id="boxout">
            <div id="boxin">3</div>
        </div>
        <div id="boxout">
            <div id="boxin">3</div>
        </div>
        <div id="boxout">
            <div id="boxin">3</div>
        </div>
        <div id="boxout">
            <div id="boxin">3</div>
        </div>
        <div id="boxout">
            <div id="boxin">3</div>
        </div>
        <div id="boxout">
            <div id="boxin">3</div>
        </div>
        <div id="boxout">
            <div id="boxin">3</div>
        </div>
        <div id="boxout">
            <div id="boxin">3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Box number 2 has the text in. I am struggling with CSS. Fullscreen here: http://jsfiddle.net/stevehomer/DyV79/, editable here http://jsfiddle.net/stevehomer/DyV79/.

I would also be interested in how to float the messages and have the overall flock of them centered, but it is not important.

Comment: 1st thing is 1st, **please *never ever*, use the same name of an `id` more than once** in your html.  **ID is a unique item**.  Instead, use a **`class`** if you have repeated items with the same styling.

Comment: Sultan thanks for that .... I do it all the time and it seems to work fine. I have always struggled with the real difference between class and ID ... In reality is it that bad?

Comment: **Class = NOT unique, ID = unique**. classes are used to apply styling to several elements and you can have several classes with a single element e.g. `<div class="navbar header fixed">` << in this `div` we applied 3 different classes.  On the other hand, ID is assigned to a unique element to distinguish it from the rest elements e.g. `<div class="navbar header fixed" id="topNavBar">` and `<div class="navbar header fixed" id="bottomNavBar">`.  You can not use the same ID with different elements.

Comment: Sultan. I hear what you say and I will be a better boy in future. Forthwith I will be compliant. And, more importantly, thanks for clearing my long suffered confusion. I would just say I have used ID in lots of pages and never had a problem. That is not to say I would not hit one in the future so from now on I will be CSS3 obedient to avoid any potential problems. Thanks again for your help. Steve

Comment: NP Steve, glad I could help. FYI, using the same ID name with several elements will not result in a direct error message, but look at it like this >> `ID = A person's Identification (ID) is unique to one person` while `Class = There are many people in a class`, e.g.  (Policemen) all policemen wear the same uniform, apply the same rules, BUT each one of them has a unique ID. I know it is little hard now to feel the differences because, one day I was in same situation but I sooner discovered the problems when I start working with `forms` and `JavaScripts` that deals with element's ID.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to put you on the right path was by creating a separate example, so hopefully you'll be able to apply this to your own layout.

[Check the example here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johntobinme/MvVV2/)

The most important thing to note is that in order to stop an element affecting other elements in the document flow, it needs `position: absolute` applied. I've included some comments along with the jsFiddle code that should fill in the other gaps.

Edit:

To center all the items, you can wrap a div around the entire group (let's call it `div id="wrapper"`, set all the boxes to `display: inline-block`, and apply `text-align: center` to the `#wrapper`. [Example of that here](http://jsfiddle.net/johntobinme/MvVV2/1/). **Or** if you only want to center the entire group (leaving the boxes to display from left to right as normal), you'll need to give your `#wrapper` a `width`, then set its `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto`. [Example of that here](http://jsfiddle.net/johntobinme/MvVV2/2/) (border added to make it a little clearer).

Comment: John - Thank you, thank you, thank you. Main question sorted. 

Don't suppose you have a solution to the supplementary - ie to get the little buggers to float centered on the page? I hasten to add this is NOTHING compared to the one you have just solved for me.

BTW including comments is very helpful and goes beyond kind. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem! I missed the last part but I've edited my answer to include a couple of options for centering.

Comment: John once again a million thanks for your help. I spent a long time looking at centering number 2 but it is still a bit too"non centered" for my liking so spent hours tinkering. I was about to go with it the saw number 1 which I prefer and will be going with. You are a man amongst men. Thank you. Aloha Steve